# runing my function in parallel using xargs

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Hi all I have the following bash script that calls hmmscan from hmmer3 software. hmmscan requires to specify 6 command line arguments in this case the code that I have written is as follows:

```
hmmscan_fun () {
    local file=$1
    local marker_profiles=$2
    local n_threads=$3
    local out_dir=$4
    fname=$(echo $file | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev)
    echo 'filename'
    echo $out_dir$fname".txt"
    echo 'n threads'
    echo $n_threads
    echo 'marker profiles'
    echo $marker_profiles
    echo $out_dir$fname".txt" >> $out_dir"out.txt"

    hmmscan -o $out_dir$fname".txt" --tblout $out_dir$fname".hmm" -E 1e-10 --cpu $n_threads $marker_profiles  $file

}
```

Basically I'm iterating over a list of files found in a directory and am running hmmscan over each file, and I'm using this file name to append on the output names so that I'll have different output names corresponding to each of my input files.

My question is that the loop is quite length and I would like to parallelize this process to scale with the number of CPUs that I provide at command line. I want to do so using xargs it is important that I use xargs since I do not have GNUs parallel function and unfortunately I cannot install anything. Please help. Basically Im stuck with how to call a function with xargs and how to pass many command line arguments to it.

Comment: How are you going to use any answer you get if you can't install anything? Are you going to copy and paste the answer you get into a script? If so, that's exactly what **GNU Parallel** is - it is a Perl script you can copy and paste.

Comment: Please look into `parallel --embed` (available since 20180222). It is made for the situation where you are not allowed to install software, but you _are_ allowed to run your own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have access to a development machine where you are allowed to install software. On that you install GNU Parallel > 20180222.

Then you run:

```
parallel --embed > myscript.sh
```

Then you change the last lines of `myscript.sh` to something like:

```
hmmscan_fun () {
    local file=$1
    local marker_profiles=$2
    local n_threads=$3
    local out_dir=$4
    fname=$(echo $file | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev)
    echo 'filename'
    echo $out_dir$fname".txt"
    echo 'n threads'
    echo $n_threads
    echo 'marker profiles'
    echo $marker_profiles
    echo $out_dir$fname".txt" >> $out_dir"out.txt"

    hmmscan -o $out_dir$fname".txt" --tblout $out_dir$fname".hmm" -E 1e-10 --cpu $n_threads $marker_profiles  $file
}
export -f hmmscan_fun

parallel hmmscan_fun {1} {2} 32 myoutdir ::: files* ::: marker1 marker2
```

And then you move the script to the production machine and run it there.